# Como bloquear função Scroll JavaScript em larguras diferentes de tela

Tags: javascript, layout-responsivo, javascript-eventos, ux

Estou com este script, ele tem a função de fazer um menu aparecer quando há algum tipo de rolagem na página, porém gostaria que a partir de certa largura de pagina este script não fosse executado. Estou aprendendo `JavaScript` e não consegui uma solução para este problema.

```
$(function(){
        var floatingChat = $("#floatingChat");
        var floatingBar=$("#floatingBar");
        var cart=$(".cart");
        var search=$(".searchBox");
        var logo=$("#header h1");
        $(window).bind("scroll",function(){         
            if($(this).scrollTop()>130){
                floatingBar.fadeTo(300,1);
                floatingChat.fadeTo(300,1);
                cart.addClass("floating");
                search.addClass("floating");
                logo.addClass("floating");
            }
            else{
                floatingChat.stop(true).css("display","none");
                floatingBar.stop(true).css("display","none");
                cart.removeClass("floating");
                search.removeClass("floating");
                logo.removeClass("floating");
            }
            if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
                floatingChat.stop(true).fadeOut(300,0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque um `if` para verificar o tamanho da tela conforme seu critério, exemplo:

```
$(function(){
var floatingChat = $("#floatingChat");
var floatingBar=$("#floatingBar");
var cart=$(".cart");
var search=$(".searchBox");
var logo=$("#header h1");
var max = 762;
$(window).bind("scroll",function(){
   if($(window).width() > max){
   ...
   }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm5vqayr/)